# ¿Cómo apagar un oscilador declarado en una función en Javascript usando el AudioContext?

Tags: javascript, html, frecuencia

Estoy trabajando en una web que reproduce ciertas frecuencias en un canal de audio y en otro (derecha y izquierda). Estoy usando el AudioContext de JavaScript.

Soy capaz de iniciar el audio en una función, usando el oscillador. En esa misma función, soy capaz de desactivar ese canal de audio (usando `leftOscillator.stop(0)`). La cuestión es que necesito desactivarlo al pulsar un botón (uso el `addEventListener('click', //aquí declaro el código)`), pero desde ahí no soy capaz de parar la reproducción de la frecuencia por ese canal de voz (en ese caso, el izquierdo).

Aquí está el código que uso:

```js
function iniciarFrequenciaLeft() {
  let rangeLeftFrec = document.getElementById('rangeLeftFrec').value;

  leftOscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
  leftGain = audioContext.createGain();
  rightOscillator = audioContext.createOscillator();
  rightGain = audioContext.createGain();
  merger = audioContext.createChannelMerger(2);

  leftOscillator.connect(leftGain).connect(merger, 0, 0);
  rightOscillator.connect(rightGain).connect(merger, 0, 1);

  merger.connect(audioContext.destination);

  leftOscillator.frequency.value = rangeLeftFrec;
  leftGain.gain.value = 0.3;
  leftOscillator.start(0);
  // Aquí puedo usar leftOscillator.stop(0);
}

// Esto ocurre cuando se pulsa un botón
avanzarLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
  leftOscillator.stop(0); // Esto no va. :(
  left.style.display = 'none';
  right.style.display = 'inline';
});
```

Ojalá podáis ayudarme, estoy completamente perdido y no consigo ejecutarlo en el addEventListener. :(

PD: Pueden ver el código completo así como el resultado aquí: [Heraning - Tinnitus](https://replit.com/@Tupiet/Hearing#script.js)

Comment: Tal vez solo necesitas declarar la variable `leftOscillator` en contexto global, fuera de funciones; o bien, poner el `addEventListener` dentro de la función. El caso es que la variable esté disponible donde la necesitas.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por responder. ¡Voy a intentarlo!